# Software to conduct a webinar

Tags: streaming, screen-sharing

I am a member of a study group in which we train each other. Many a times, we need to conduct a *webinar-like* event.

The requirements of software are :

1. Trainer can share **an application window** .The size of the application window can be customized. For example, application window that is being used can have different size than what is desired to broadcast.
2. Trainer can share **screen**, including whole desktop.
3. Visibility of trainer can be changed
4. If any attendee has a doubt, he can **be given permission** to share its screen/webcam/microphone
5. Attendes can interact in real time with the trainer. However, interaction can be moderated by the trainer
6. Should be free

I am using OBS and found to fulfil most of my requirements. However the following issues are coming.

- Application window cannot be shared. A black/white box appears *even after disabling hardware acceleration option*
- No dropdown menus appear in application window
- No support for requirement 4

[image: OBS issues]

P.S. I am using OBS Studio 18.0.1(64-bit)

Comment: I think Big Blue Button can do most of what you are asking I think, but it has been a few years since I looked at it.  I do know that it requires flash for basic use and java for the window/desktop sharing if that matters.